# How to modify colors using Rselenium?

Tags: r, rselenium

I would like to change the color of the foreground and background color in this website (https://www.qrcode-monkey.com/#url)
using `Rselenium`

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We must first clear the field to set new values,

```
#launch browser
driver = rsDriver(browser = c("firefox"))
remDr <- driver[["client"]]
remDr$navigate('https://www.qrcode-monkey.com/#url')

remDr$findElement('xpath', '/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[1]/h3')$clickElement()
remDr$findElement(using = "xpath", '/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[4]/div/color-picker/div/div[1]/input')$clickElement()
webElem = remDr$findElement(using = "xpath", '/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[4]/div/color-picker/div/div[1]/input')
webElem$sendKeysToElement(list(key = 'backspace'))  #repeat the step six times to clear the field
#set color to red
webElem$sendKeysToElement(list("#FF0000"))
```